# Extracting a function which creates an instance in Rust

Tags: rust

A bit of a beginner Rust question - say I have the following code, which compiles:

```rust
trait XGetter {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Foo {
    x: i32
}
impl XGetter for Foo {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.x
    }
}

struct Bar<'a>(&'a dyn XGetter);
impl<'a> XGetter for Bar<'a> {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0.get_x()
    }
}

fn baz() -> i32 {
    let foo = Foo { x: 42 };
    let bar = Bar(&foo);
    bar.get_x()
}
```

Let's say I want to extract out the creation of `Bar`, in order encapsulate the creation of the `XGetter` and `Bar` together, such that `baz()` now reads:

```rust
fn baz2() -> i32 {
    let bar = createBar(42);
    bar.get_x()
}
```

However, by implementing `createBar` below, I run a-fowl of the borrow checker:

```rust
fn createBar<'a>(x: i32) -> Bar<'a> {
    let foo = Foo { x };
    let bar = Bar(&foo);
//                ---- `foo` is borrowed here
    bar
//  ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
}
```

**How would one extract out a function `createBar` which doesn't break the borrowing rules?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `foo` in `createBar()` dies when the function ends, so the `bar` you return would be pointing to invalid memory.

Given how you have written the call to `createBar(42)`, it looks like you want `Bar` to *own* the `Foo`, so do that:

```
struct Bar(Box<dyn XGetter>);

impl XGetter for Bar {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0.get_x()
    }
}

fn createBar(x: i32) -> Bar {
    let foo = Box::new(Foo { x });
    let bar = Bar(foo);
    bar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can not**:

The signature `struct Bar<'a>(&'a dyn XGetter);` and `createBar(i: 32)` are incompatible. Because it means that in `createBar` you would have to instantiate an object implementing XGetter and that reference will not live outside of the scope of `createBar`.

```rust
fn createBar<'a>(x: i32) -> Bar<'a> {
    let foo = Foo { x };
    let bar = Bar(&foo);
//                ---- `foo` is borrowed here
    bar
//  ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
}
```

^^^ That means that the variable `foo` will live just during `createBar` scope.

That said, you could use:

```rust
fn createBar(g: &dyn XGetter) -> Bar<'_> {
    Bar(g)
}
```

That way the reference will live outside of the scope of `createBar`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69e394102ebf414f1ab9ca548d64a0ba)

As per the comments. If you want to abstract that, you need `Bar` to **own** `Foo`

```rust
struct Bar(Box<dyn XGetter>);


fn createBar(x: i32) -> Bar {
    let foo = Box::new(Foo { x });
    let bar = Bar(foo);
    bar
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However then `createBar` has no purpose above the constructor itself. The idea is to encapsulate the creation of the `XGetter` to be an instance of `Foo` within the `createBar` function.

Comment: @dav_i, exatly. It has no sense. You should not use a reference then but make `Bar` own `Foo`